# How to set a specific condition to a new Parameter in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have an existing code, to which I have to add new Parameter -
@Depreciation 'Yes' or 'No'

if @Depreciation = 1  (which I believe corresponds to 'Yes') 
then I want the certain condition of an existing code will be 
FALSE (I marked that code section with the '-- ***' ),

and the vise versa -

if @Depreciation = 0 ('No')
then I want that condition in the code will be 
TRUE

The conditions is

```
 (NOT (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130')))
```

located after the 1st WHERE in the code below.

Please, don't pay too much attention to the entire code.
The only parts that I have to modify are - 
'**DECLARE @Depreciation**....'
and **after the first 'WHERE** ..... '  - I marked with -- ***

```
     DECLARE @FYMonthBOP date = '07-01-2016'
     DECLARE @FYMonthEOP date = '07-01-2018'
     DECLARE @GLProgramGroupsWHID int = -1
     DECLARE @GLProgramsWHID_Groups int = -1
     DECLARE @GLProgramGroupSetsWHID int = -1

     DECLARE @Depreciation bit = 1 -- *** This is my added Parameter

    SELECT        
       gl0.GLGroupLevel0Name
     , gl0.Ordinal AS Ordinal0
     , [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.GLGroupLevel1Name
     , [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.Ordinal AS Ordinal1
     , gl2.GLGroupLevel2Name
     , gl2.Ordinal AS Ordinal2
     , acct.GLAccountCode
     , acct.GLAccountName
     , setname.WHID AS WHIDGroupSetName
     , setname.GroupSetName
     , pgm.GLProgramCode + N' ' + pgm.GLProgramName AS Program
     , grp.GroupName
     , grp.WHID AS WHIDGroupName
     , grp.Ordinal AS OrdinalGroupName 
     , d.FYQuarterLabel AS FQ
     , trans.Amount AS Amount
     , pgm.[WHID] AS WHIDProgram
     , pgm.Ordinal AS OrdinalProgram
     , d.FYMonthNumber
     , d.FYMonthShortLabel
     , d.FYQuarterNumber
     , d.FYNumber
     , d.FYLabel
     , d.YearMonthSort
     , IIF(EOMonth(mm.DateThru) < @FYMonthEOP, EOMonth(mm.DateThru), 
            @FYMonthEOP) AS [DateThru]

 FROM            
       ([Dimension].GLGroupLevel2 gl2
      INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLAccount acct ON gl2.[WHID] = 
                                               acct.GLGroupLevel2FK 
      INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLGroupLevel0 gl0
      INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1 ON gl0.[WHID] = 
                 [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.GLGroupLevel0FK ON 
                             gl2.GLGroupLevel1FK = 
                             [Dimension].GLGroupLevel1.[WHID] 
      INNER JOIN Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly trans ON acct.[WHID] = 
                                            trans.GLAccountFK 
      INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLProgram pgm ON trans.[GLProgramFK] = 
                 pgm.[WHID] AND trans.[GLProgramFK] = 
                 pgm.[WHID] AND trans.[GLProgramFK] = pgm.[WHID] 
      INNER JOIN [Dimension].[Date] d ON trans.EffectiveMonth = d.[Date] 
                 AND trans.EffectiveMonth = d.[Date] 
                 AND trans.EffectiveMonth = d.[Date] 
      INNER JOIN [Dimension].GLRegion ON pgm.GLRegionFK = 
                 [Dimension].GLRegion.[WHID] AND pgm.GLRegionFK = 
                 [Dimension].GLRegion.[WHID]
      INNER JOIN [Reports].GLProgramGroupMapping map ON map.GLProgramFK = 
                                                        pgm.[WHID]
      INNER JOIN [Reports].GLProgramGroup grp ON grp.WHID = 
                                                 map.GLProgramGroupFK
      INNER JOIN [Reports].GLProgramGroupSet setname ON setname.WHID = 
                                             grp.GLProgramGroupSetFK)


        CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(t.EffectiveMonth) AS [DateThru] FROM 
                        Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly t WITH (NoLock)) mm


-- *** This, below -    

WHERE (
 (NOT (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130'))) 

-- *** is the condition I want to execute, if my Parameter = False, and not 
-- *** to execute, if my Parameter = True  


   AND  (trans.[EffectiveMonth] BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP) 
   AND ((setname.WHID IN (@GLProgramGroupSetsWHID)) OR (-1 IN 
     (@GLProgramGroupSetsWHID)))
   AND ((grp.WHID IN (@GLProgramGroupsWHID)) OR (-1 IN 
                               (@GLProgramGroupsWHID)))
   AND ((pgm.[WHID] IN (@GLProgramsWHID_Groups)) OR 
                        (-1 IN (@GLProgramsWHID_Groups)))   


   AND (
       (pgm.[WHID] IN (
       SELECT DISTINCT      
            f.[GLProgramFK]

       FROM            
           Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly f
           INNER JOIN [Dimension].[GLAccount] acct ON 
                      f.[GLAccountFK] = acct.[WHID]

       WHERE 
            (f.[EffectiveMonth] BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP)
            AND (NOT (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047'))) 
            AND (acct.[GLAccountCode] BETWEEN '5000' AND '9999') 

        GROUP BY
            f.[GLProgramFK]

            HAVING 
              (SUM(f.[Amount]) <> 0))
           )
     OR
        (pgm.[WHID] IN (
                   SELECT DISTINCT      
                         f.[GLProgramFK]

                 FROM            
                    Fact.GLTransactionsMonthly f
                         INNER JOIN [Dimension].[GLAccount] acct ON 
                                    f.[GLAccountFK] = acct.[WHID]

                       WHERE 
                   (f.[EffectiveMonth] BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP)
                     AND (NOT (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'4130'))) 
                     AND (acct.[GLAccountCode] BETWEEN '4000' AND '4999') 

                         GROUP BY
                               f.[GLProgramFK]

                                  HAVING 
                                       (SUM(f.[Amount]) <> 0))
                                )
                     OR 
                              (pgm.[GLProgramCode] IN ('549'))
                            )   
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
(
  (
    @Depreciation = 0 /* FALSE AND EXISTING CONDITION */
    and NOT (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130'))
  )
  or
  (
    @Depreciation = 1 /* OR TRUE AND NOT EXISTING CONDITION */
    and (acct.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130'))
  )
)
```

Comment: You have a very complex query - and adding `OR` conditions frequently slows things down. A quick solution can be to `union all` each condition i.e. create 2 queries one for each branch of an `OR` condition, and then union all the queries together. No promises though, as I said thats a pretty complex query - personally I'd probably break it down.

Comment: It's the way you're using the @Depreciation parameter... The optimizer has to come up with an execution plan BEFORE it know what the value of @Depreciation is going to be. So, It chooses a "safe" scan operation that works (poorly) for either value. Try adding `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the end of your query. `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`will cause the optimizer to recompile a new plan AFTER it has the parameter values and will create a plan optimized specifically for that set of parameter values.

Comment: Actually, the problem of the slow execution was because I used to large interval in the other parameters.
This is no longer a problem, it works fast!
But I still having mismatch in the expected amount of data (when I compare the original query)
As I see, it because the query is too complex, there are few more places I have to modify ... !!!
Thank you, all